# How to extract ucas and utoc io store container files in unreal engine 5

Tags: unpacking

I tried to use different programs for this, such as fmodel and UnrealPakViewer, but fmodel support only utoc, so I can extract only some part of files and it does not support binka audio files. UnrealPakViewer can open ucas and I can see files in it, but I cant unpack these files.

Files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1W5cv3n6cgVFx18W6_A1Rqo350-TeLlCV?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 4 tools that allow to extract files from iostore containers:

https://github.com/gitMenv/UEcastoc/

https://github.com/rm-NoobInCoding/UnrealUnZen

https://github.com/Archengius/ZenTools/

https://fmodel.app

The last 2 only allow to extract, while the first 2 allow to extract and then pack back, or so they claim.

Also, check out this repository:

https://github.com/Buckminsterfullerene02/UE-Modding-Tools

It gets updated, so in the future you might find more tools there.